# svn diff -c: Omitting copied files?

Tags: svn

If I copy a file in the repository using the svn copy command, the "svn diff -c" command will show all lines of the copied files. How can I omit copied files from showing in the diff?

If I view the changeset of the revision in Trac for example, no diff is shown (just says the file is copied).

This is the command I use:
svn diff -c REVISION SVNURL --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In small scale; first run `svn diff -c REVISION --summarize` which shows what files are merged and what files are new etc. Then, do your thing. Just ignore the diffs for merged files shown by first command.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Once I know what files have been copied, how can I exclude files from the svn diff command (as the multiple files may have been committed and only some of them are copied)? There doesn't seem to be any --exclude option available. Or do I have to run a diff command for each file in the revision?

Comment: I don't see any option like that either. You may have to write some script for the diffed content to strip out unneeded-diff-files, which you identified via the above command. diffs has a standard structure, so this should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that requires a bit of programming:

```
svn log URL -c REVISION --xml -v
```

With this command you have a clear indication of what was copied. You can then parse the XML output and use it to filter the output of `svn diff -c`

Example of output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="REVISION">
<author>EMAIL</author>
<date>YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.UUUUUUZ</date>
<paths>
<path
   copyfrom-path="/OLD_PATH"
   copyfrom-rev="OLDER_REVISION"
   action="A"
   prop-mods="false"
   text-mods="false"
   kind="dir">/NEW_PATH</path>
</paths>
<msg>Copy a file</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54459483).