# How to find the path a file was copied from in subversion

Tags: svn, diff

In subversion, if I move a file using `svn move foo.py bar.py` then `svn status` helpfully shows me where the file was moved from

```
$ svn move foo.py bar.py
$ svn status
A  +    bar.py
    > moved from foo.py
```

If I do a copy on the other hand, the output doesn't show where the new file was copied from:

```
$ svn copy foo.py bar.py
$ svn status
A  +    bar.py
```

Is there any way to find where bar.py was copied from. If I modify `bar.py`, `svn diff` shows the changes relative to the original `foo.py`, but unfortunately the header incorrectly shows the original file path as `bar.py` at some revision which doesn't exist in the repo yet.

```
Index: bar.py
===================================================================
--- bar.py   (revision 14283)
+++ bar.py   (working copy)
@@ -1,15 +1,14 @@

....
```

I need to produce diffs to send to my code-review tool, and it gets upset because `bar.py` doesn't exist in the repository at the revision claimed in the diff.

Answer (score 2):

The `svn log` command has a `verbose` option. This will also print the path from which the file was copied.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html

Example:

```
svn log URL -c REVISION --xml -v
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="REVISION">
<author>EMAIL</author>
<date>YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.UUUUUUZ</date>
<paths>
<path
   copyfrom-path="/OLD_PATH"
   copyfrom-rev="OLDER_REVISION"
   action="A"
   prop-mods="false"
   text-mods="false"
   kind="dir">/NEW_PATH</path>
</paths>
<msg>Copy a file</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

Comment: Right, but this only works *after* committing. I'm talking about uncommitted local changes (that are shown up by `svn status' or `svn log').

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your code review tool ingests only diff. You have two operations, copy and edit, which your tool needs to know about. A simple `svn diff` reports only the editing and not the copy.

Here are three possible way around your problem. I cannot test your tool, so I cannot tell if any will work, but worth a shot:

1. Use: `svn diff --show-copies-as-adds`. This will show the previous version of the file as non-existent. Compare (file4 is a svn-copied and edited file):

   ```
   [843] >>> svn diff
   Index: file4
   ===================================================================
   --- file4   (revision 5)
   +++ file4   (working copy)
   @@ -1 +1,2 @@
    some text
   +more more
   ```

   with

   ```
   [844] >>> svn diff --show-copies-as-adds
   Index: file4
   ===================================================================
   --- file4   (nonexistent)
   +++ file4   (working copy)
   @@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
   +some text
   +more more
   ```
2. Commit and then `svn diff -r PREV` (you can always rollback the commit afterwards). You will get the same result:

   ```
   [845] >>> svn ci -m "copied and edited"
   Adding         file4
   Transmitting file data .done
   Committing transaction...
   Committed revision 6.

   [846] >>> svn up
   Updating '.':
   At revision 6.

   [847] >>> svn diff -r PREV
   Index: file4
   ===================================================================
   --- file4   (nonexistent)
   +++ file4   (revision 6)
   @@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
   +some text
   +more more
   ```
3. Separate you workflow in two steps. First commit the duplication of the file before editing. Then do your editing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1) is our current work-around, but isn't very satisfactory as it doesn't show what has changed from the original. 2) just doesnt work for us as all commits must be reviewed before committing. 3) works but is a pain. It's annoying that SVN doesn't expose information that it clearly has.

Comment: @NickEdwards isn't « all commits must be reviewed before committing » a contradiction ? Not arguing, we've got the need, and simply commit, then review, and this is not satisfactory sometimes, but is most of the time.

Comment: Ok: "All change-sets must be reviewed before committing"